# Recomended GWT Frameworks for single page application

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, frameworks

After google around, I have to ask this question on StackOverflow.

There are frameworks around, but most of them are from 2008 2009, unmaintained, multipage or will not work with GWT 2.0

What are the recommended framework should I use for a single page application that will scale most in term of deploy? 1 language is a plus point because GWT is all about 1 language, beside if we tune the server to run Java and serve HTML pages, it will be faster.

But any framework that works and good is okay also.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by a framework?  GWT is a framework.

Comment: I still don't understand what's a "framework for single page application" and how is GWT not a framework :/

Comment: Framework, in this case, you can call it platform or something. Using a framework to create an app is much faster and helps give you more separation of layer. This is what i am looking for. GWT is a framework itself for javascript, but there gonna be different ways of implement on both client and backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Jay Askren's suggestions, another good framework is [gwt-platform](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/), which is a combination of two other good frameworks, [gwt-presenter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/) and [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/).

Comment: This is it. pretty framework with lot of documents and stuff. Recomended gwt-platform. but i will still looking for better framework :) Open for any suggestion :))

Comment: What do you mean a better framework!? -- GWTP's author. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend watching t[his from last year's Google IO](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html).  They recommended using the Model-View-Presenter pattern for GWT apps.  [Here is one implementation of this pattern](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mvp/).
The following from this year's GoogleIO might also be helpful:

- http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/architecting-performance-gwt.html
- http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/architecting-production-gwt.html

I should also mention that GWT is a framework in and of itself.  The above are more best practices on how to use the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Sencha GXT? It's a single page framework.

http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/

Comment: ExtGWT and SmartGWT are now commercial product. In case when you develop something. it will cost. Not recommended.

Comment: Ext GWT is dual licensed, GPL/Commercial. If you're using it for an in-house app, you're fine. It's only when you serve an app to someone outside your company that you have to provide source.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's also important to note that [GWT 2.1](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/ReleaseNotes.html) will include a lot of application framework pieces. From what I've seen so far on the contributor mailing list, it should include:

- MVP framework
- EventBus integration
- PlaceManager for navigation
- Data presentation widgets (i.e. data binding)
- Validation hooks? (JSR-303 annotations recently committed)

So make sure to check out vanilla GWT 2.1 M2 as well.